# Foreach Sub Item In ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I was wanting to be able to iterate through each of my ListViews sub items and get the value from each. I have tried various things but am finding it really difficult to just get the sub item text from the second column, not the items text from the first column. Thanks.

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in listView1.Items)
{             
    for (int i = 0; i < itemRow.SubItems.Count; i++) 
    {
        string dueDate = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
        MessageBox.Show(dueDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I managed to do it with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int ii = 1;
    MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[ii].Text);
    ii++;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you implement `ii` into the parameters of your for-loop? ****some space for readability**** `(int i=0, int ii=1; i<listView1.Items.Count;i++,ii++)`

Answer (score 4):

Check this code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.loggerlistView.Items)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < itemRow.SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return itemRow.SubItems[i]);
    }
}
```

Also check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx)

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but I can't get it to compile, what return type do I use for the method as it is yield return? I tried void and static/void but no joy, please help! Thanks!

Comment: You can run it with both void and static/void. It is working perfectly on my side and i am also getting sub item value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works very easy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
listView.Items[i].Subitems[1].tostring();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usedDatesList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < usedDatesList.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(usedDatesList.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to get the values of subitems from the first selected item. try this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem a in listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems)
    MessageBox.Show(a.Text );
```

if you want to get the value from the entire listview or multi-selection, then you have to use 2 foreach loop.